# No data sources available nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to install  saucy-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip  and saucy-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip   They install successfully but when I reboot I get a screen that has a circle that says, "No data sources available" I have searched Google to find http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2538219 which is for the Nexus 4 and doesn't solve the problem. Is there a way to install Ubuntu Touch through ClockworkMod Touch Recovery? Is Multirom necessary in this scenario? thanks in advance

Comment: Try pushing that screen out of the way.

Comment: I was able to push the screen out of the way but could not update via updates or via command line. So I installed Trusty tahr and encountered the same issues. I get a message to sign into my Ubuntu One account which I did, and still cannot update via command line or Updates. When trying via command line I can type commands in but cannot backspace or get enter to actually work. ny suggestions?

Comment: Go into system settings and try updating from there.

Comment: I just today tried the Dual boot on my nexus 7 and it to worked. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation

Comment: I tried system settings update and it just hangs. Will try it again

Comment: Which Nexus 7 do you have? afaik, development on the old Nexus 7 has stalled in favour of the new nexus 7. Could be your issue.